# Fby q/kdb aggregation function

Tags: kdb

I want to apply an `fby` using `count distinct`, i.e.

```
select from t where 1=(count distinct; column) fby another_column
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what's already up there you could do this in less characters with an @ apply

```
q)n:100
// Create a table where all entries for sym=`a are size 10
q)show t:update size:10 from ([]sym:n#`a`b`c`d;size:n?200) where sym = `a
sym size
--------
a   10
b   28
c   51
d   64
a   10
b   43
...
// Use count distinct@ to select from the table as per your requirements
q)select from t where 1=(count distinct@;size) fby sym
sym size
--------
a   10
a   10
a   10
a   10
a   10
```

`0N!` is a great operator for checking the operation of these queries 'in-flight'
Using it we can see `count distinct` fails on it's own because it tries to count the function `distinct` which returns 1

```
q)select from t where 1=(0N!count distinct; size) fby sym
1
'type
  [0]  select from t where 1=(0N!count distinct; size) fby sym
```

However with dyadic @ we can create a handy projection

```
q)select from t where 1=(0N!(count distinct@); size) fby sym
#@[?:]
sym size
--------
a   10
a   10
a   10
a   10
...
```

Here I've had to wrap using brackets here to prevent 0N! getting sucked into the `count distinct @` projection. In k-speak this effectively translates to 'count the result of the distinct operator applied to whatever the second argument to @ is'. Quite handy for code-golfing

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier to know for sure if you provide a sample table and desired output, but one of the following will likely help.

The simplest solution would be to use an anonymous function:

```
select from t where 1=({count distinct x};c1) fby c2
```

Alternatively you can use this syntax which I first saw used in Nick Psaris' new book Fun Q:

```
select from t where 1=(count distinct ::;c1) fby c2
```

Comment: what is the second doing ? what's the explanation for that